# Unable to run Linux Docker Containers on Windows Server 2019 on AWS

Tags: docker

I have a windows server 2019 on AWS, and I have installed and setup Linux Docker Container following the instructions below.

```
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force

Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force

Restart-Computer

$configfile =@"
{
    "experimental":true
}
"@

$configfile|Out-File -FilePath c:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json -Encoding ascii -Force

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://github.com/linuxkit/lcow/releases/download/v4.14.35-v0.3.9/release.zip" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile release.zip
Expand-Archive release.zip -DestinationPath "$Env:ProgramFiles\Linux Containers\."

Restart-Service Docker
```

However, I get the following error when running any Linux image:

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run --rm -it --platform=linux ubuntu bash
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 4242d968c7830dd923c657267486ea32ae9d843c76041d3b4beb39146efc5ea2_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"4242d968c7830dd923c657267486ea32ae9d843c76041d3b4beb39146efc5ea2_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Also, the container feature and Hyper-V role are enabled.

Here is the docker version information.

[image]

I have followed most of the articles, blogs and spent the last few hours with different versions of Docker EE (including preview) but to no avail. Has anyone been able to solve a similar problem? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.